# How come navigation isn't against the wrapper when there is no margins/padding?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I don't want space above the navigation div. Does it add space as default?
In design view, this is no space. But in preview, there is space. Please help. I tried this  but didn't work.

My coding is:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="nav">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
CSS:
.nav ul li {
float: right;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #000;
}
.nav ul li a {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: center;
height: 36px;
width: 80px;
line-height: 36px;
background-color: #FFF;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
color: #F00;
}
.nav {
margins: 0px;
}

body {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

}

```
#container {
background-color: #CCC;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Comment: I tried <body topmargin="0"> but didn't work

Comment: Can you include your current css?

Comment: metaColin spotted it with .nav ul {margin: 0;}. If you just want to remove the top margin .nav ul {margin-top: 0;}. Also there is not margins rule - keep it as nav {margin: 0;}. No px required on a 0 measurement either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your current CSS looks like, but here is a basic example that illustrates what I think you are trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/tfb2L5vd/

```
.nav {
    background:#eee;
}

body {
    margin:0;
}

ul {
    margin:0;
}
```

I've stripped margins from both the  as well as the  elements to remove spacing from the top of the page. Background color added for emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is margins being added to some of your elements by browser specific default styles. Try  explicitly defining zero margin on those elements. In particular that  element (and the html & body just to be safe).

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
}
.nav ul{
    margin:0;
}
```

Fixed example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbWZoW